# Comic book with a boy and animals

Tags: story-identification, comics

I read this comic book as a child, but can't recall its name and Google couldn't help.
It's about a boy and lots of animals. As far as I can remember the boy regularly enters a dream-world, where he encounters a lot of different animals (can't remember what exactly he was doing there). His mother gives him a goldfish, which he names Moby Dick. This fish also enters the dream world.

In my version the first two pages of the book contained a huge picture of different animals (whale, penguin & others).I read it in German, not sure if this was the original language or a translation.
Anybody know what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is *[Hé, Nic! Tu rêves?](https://web.archive.org/web/20171129214046/http://www.hermannhuppen.com/biblio-nic.shtml)* (*Hey, Nick! Are You Dreaming?*), the first book of a Belgian series about a boy named Nic and the adventures he has while dreaming. According to [French WikiPedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nic_(bande_dessin%C3%A9e)), it was heavily inspried by *[Little Nemo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Nemo)*.

[image: Cover of Hé, Nic! Tu rêves? Nic, a white boy with dark brown hair in red pyjamas, sits on a flying white goose, above a dark orange sea against a lighter orange to yellow sky. Behind him we see a hot air balloon and a boat on the horizon.]

It was written by [Morphée (Philippe Vandooren)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Vandooren), drawn by [Hermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Huppen) (best known for *[Jeremiah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremiah_(comics))*) and colouring was done by [Vittorio Leonardo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vittorio_Leonardo). It was published by Dupuis.

It consists of a number of linked stories, each starting when Nic falls asleep. He dreams another chapter of his adventure, somewhat related to what he did before falling asleep. The major antagonist is Captain Bang, who wants to capture all the animals for his zoo. Nic tries to thwart his plans. When he succeeds, the captain gets so mad that he explodes with a bang, leaving only his hat behind.

[image: Captain Bang! Two panels from the comic, showing Captain Bang exploding. In the first panel we see a pinkish cloud, the captain's pink hat flaoting above it. Purple letters read BANG. In the second panel, the cloud has vanished and the hat drops on the ground.]

---

The German version is called *He, Robin. Träumst Du?* and is [available on Amazon.de](https://www.amazon.de/Tr%C3%A4ume-kleinen-Robin-Robin-Tr%C3%A4umst/dp/3551018154).

Comment: That's it! Thank you

Comment: @quirmel Funny thing is that I recently considered asking this exact question myself (only I read it in Dutch). But it was surprisingly easy to find, actually, probably because I remembered more details.